# selecting rows based on multiple columns

Tags: database

Suppose i have a table like below

```
reg   sub1   sub2   sub3
1      A      F      F
2      F      F      A
3      A      B      B
4      A      B      F
5      A      F      F
```

sub1, sub2, sub3 are the three different subjects and the values A, B & F are the grades where A and B holds certain points but F is fail....Now i want the reg of students who has one 'F'(i.e Failed in only one subject) and two subjects, 3 subjects and so on....How to do tat.....

My desired output for students with one F(i.e Failed in only one subject) is...

```
   reg   sub1   sub2   sub3
    4      A      B      F
```

and students with two F(i.e Failed in two subjects)  is...

```
   reg   sub1   sub2   sub3
    1      A      F      F
    2      F      F      A    
    5      A      F      F
```

Comment: Would be much easier if your table was designed differently - you shouldn't have one column per "exam". You should have columns like `student_id,exam,grade`, one row per exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, like @Mat said in a comment above, this would be much easier if you normalised your data model.

Second, I'll be assuming that you are looking for a SQL query. Third, since you didn't mention at all what database system you are using (SQL Server, DB2, Oracle, Postgres, etc.), I will show a solution that works at least for SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM grades
WHERE (CASE sub1 WHEN 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
      (CASE sub2 WHEN 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
      (CASE sub3 WHEN 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
```

This would find all records in your table (`grades`) with exactly 2 `F` grades. What it does is to convert each `F` into a 1, and every other grade into 0, then it builds the sum of these numbers. That is, it computes the number of `F`s for each record.

Comment: Thank u bro i got the result....sry for not mentioning the DB i m using IBM Db2.....On ur advice of normalizing table, bro actually i just wanna display reg, marks of their 3 subjects as above including additional details like their total, rank,etc...So how can i modify my table....if there is any better design plz say me bro i m ready to accept it

Comment: One more doubt bro how to get the subject name in which the student got 'F'

Comment: That is a different question altogether. Let me just say that much: 1. Your data model does not contain subject name data, so that is impossible. 2. That additional question only makes sense for queries for 1 failed exam; if you query for 2 failed exams, there is no single subject that the student failed. 3. This would all be easier if you changed your data model.

Comment: bro i just modified ur solution like this..... `SELECT reg, CASE WHEN sub1 = 'F' THEN 'sub1' END AS Result FROM grades`  this displays final result with `reg` and `sub1` if sub1 is `F` suppose if i extend the above case to other subjects it prints as `sub1` if the first cond satisfies  suppose if second cond also satisfies `i.e if sub2 is also 'F'` it is not added to the already displayed sub1 (if I consider so)....my question is  there any way to concat the previously displayed value `for eg. 'sub1'` with next value to be displayed suppose `sub2`.....